# Scanf keeps waiting for input after a string with spaces is entered?

Tags: string, input, scanf, spaces

This is the function that captures the string:

```
void capture(char string[]) {
    printf("_____________________________________________________________\n\n");
    printf("Ingrese una cadena: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", string);
    printf("Cadena capturada: %s\n", string);
    printf("_____________________________________________________________\n\n");
}
```

This is the function that is being called in the main function:

```
    void sort(char string[]) {  
int opt, i, j, temp = 0;
char string_copy[50];
strcpy(string_copy, string);
for (i = 0; string_copy[i] != '\0'; i++) 
    for (i = 0; string_copy[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; string_copy[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (string_copy[i] > string_copy[j]) {
                temp = string_copy[i];
                string_copy[i] = string_copy[j];
                string_copy[j] = temp;
            }
            }
            }

printf("_____________________________________________________________\n\n");
printf("Ordenar de modo:\n1) Ascendente\n2) Descendente\n");
printf("Seleccione una opcion: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf(" %d", &opt);
switch(opt) {
    case 1: 
            printf("'%s' ordenado de forma ascendente: %s\n", string, string_copy);
            break;
    case 2: 
            printf("'%s' ordenado de forma descendente: ", string);
            for (i=strlen(string); i != 0; i--)
                printf("%c", string_copy[i]);
            printf("\n");
            break;
    default: printf("[ ! ] Selección incorrecta!\n"); break;
}
printf("_____________________________________________________________\n\n");
}

//Imprimir la última palabra de la cadena
void last_word(char string[50]) {
    printf("_____________________________________________________________\n\n");
    int i, count = 0;
    for (i=0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (string[i] == ' ') {
            count = i;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        printf("Solamente hay una palabra: %s\n", string);
    } else {
        printf("La última palabra en '%s' es: ", string);
        for (i=count; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            printf("%c", string[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("_____________________________________________________________\n\n");
}
```

And this is the code that has the problem:

```
int main() {
int opc = 0;
char string[50];
do {
    printf("MENU:\n");
    printf("1) Capturar cadena\n");
    printf("2) Sustituir un caracter por otro\n");
    printf("3) Buscar un caracter e imprimir el número de veces que aparece\n");
    printf("4) Buscar un caracter para eliminar de la cadena.\n");
    printf("5) Ordenar los caracteres alfabéticamente\n");
    printf("6) Imprimir la última palabra de la cadena\n");
    printf("0) Salir\n");
    printf("Seleccione una opcion: ");
    scanf("%i", &opc);
    printf("Opcion: %d", opc);
    switch(opc) {
        case 1:{
                capture(string);
                break;
        }
        case 2:{
                replace(string);
                break;
        }
        case 3:{
                num_char(string);
                break;
        }
        case 4:{
                delete(string);
                break;
        }
        case 5:{
                sort(string);
                break;
        }
        case 6:{
                last_word(string);
                break;
        }
        case 0:{
                printf("Bye\n");
                break;
        }
        default: {
                printf("[ ! ] Selección incorrecta!\n");
        }
    }
} while (opc != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is with option five above in the switch case: It only executes if the captured string does not have any spaces. If you would input "Hello world" for example. Case 5 will never execute and the scanf

```
printf("Seleccione una opcion: ");
scanf("%i", &opc);
```

Will just stay there waiting for an input. This only happens, I repeat, if the string captured has spaces **AND** you choose option *five* in the switch case.

Comment: I wonder if there is some error or endless loop in the function `sort`...

Comment: @GenoChen Added the sort function to the original post.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Because if I don't, Visual Basic gives me the error 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' :(

Comment: @UrielGuzmán If you made changes you don't understand to fix bugs, you should take them out before you ask for help and post the code that you think should work. Otherwise, the help you get may leave you back where you were in the first place and, worse, it's advice about code you didn't understand and wouldn't have written. (Likely the answer I gave you just puts you back where you were before you broke your code more trying to fix it. Sorry.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks. I fixed the array problems in the original post. But the problem is still occurring.

Answer (score 1):

```
            capture(&string[50]);
```

You are passing `capture` the address of `string[50]`. But there is no `string[50]`. So you are passing an address past the end of `string` to `capture`. (Since `string` has fifty entries and `0` is the first, `49` is the last. There is no `string[50]`, it's past the end of the array.

```
void capture(char string[50]) {
    printf("_____________________________________________________________\n\n");
    printf("Ingrese una cadena: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", string);
    printf("Cadena capturada: %s\n", string);
    printf("_____________________________________________________________\n\n");
}
```

Ooops, `capture` writes to the address it was past for `string`, but that's past the end of the array you allocated. Writing to memory outside the bounds you allocated can trample other variables and cause unpredictable results. Until you fix out of bounds writes, you really can't debug anything else in your program. You can use `valgrind` or a similar tool to help detect these kinds of errors.

Comment: It seems I was incorrectly passing arrays to the function. Fixed that in the original post. However, the problem still remains. PS: The program crashes as it waits for the input. It looks like an infinite loop problem too.

Comment: You hit the core of the question. I tried gdb on my device, and found a stack smashing after `return 0;` of `main`. But I don't know why it is at this statement.

Comment: Oh, for the original question's code, even `string` and `string_copy` are rewritten into some unexpected value...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your logic and it seems there is a problem in there:

Why are you passing string[50] to each function? I assume you would like to use the same string variable in every function, so, there's two points for you to check:

1. You should ask for the user to enter the string value before the switch() statement - call capture() in the row before the switch() line, for example. Otherwise, the user could enter other menu options before entering the "capture" function, and, in this case the string will not exist yet, causing a segmentation error - if I'm not mistaken. (Have you tried it? Choosing option 3, for example, before choosing option 1? It must not work)
2. To pass the "string" variable by parameter, use "string", not "string[50]".
   After the declaration (where "50" is the size of the string), the expression "string[50]" represents the 50th value of the string, which doesn't even exist, as pointed in David's answer.

Comment: Yes. David was right about that one. Already corrected the string parameters in the original post a few minutes ago. (It's now passing string instead of &string[50]). The segmentation error disappeared after I corrected it, though. But the original problem of the question still remains. I also just did what you said in point 1. Allthough it didn't fix the problem. I will keep it like that because, as you said, it's better to have the string captured before anything else.

Comment: Have you checked issue number 1?

Comment: I also don't understand the line "scanf(" %[^\n]s", string);" in function capture().
Have you tried using just "scanf("%50c", string)" ?

%s reads any number of non-whitespace characters, stopping at the first whitespace character found. A terminating null character is automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/
You make take a look there ...

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. I meant I corrected issue 1 (and 2 too). scanf(" %[^\n]s", string); is for accepting string with spaces, stopping until the newline character is encountered. I left a space at first, because the newline character of the option menu was messing with the scanf. Tried fgets() and even using getchar() to eat the newline character but they seem to have nothing to do with the original problem.

Comment: I see.. I'll need to leave right now, but I can try to help you later if the problem persists. I reccomended a link for you in the previous comment, hope it helps.. ': )

Comment: "scanf("%50c", string)" Made the input freeze just like the original problem. It asks for an input but never delivers any output. Hope you can help me later. Seems like I'll be stuck here for some time :)

Comment: hello again. If every other function is working, I believe now the error is occuring inside the sort() function. I don't understand why you have identical "for" loops using the same variable "i"...